# In R. For Low and High income, what percentage of each were given a loan

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

In R. For Low and High income, what percentage of each were given a loan (Loan_Given == 'Y'). Below is my dataset.

```
Income_Level <- c('High','Low','Low','High',
                  'Low','High','High','High','Low','Low','High','Low')
Loan_Given <- c('Y','N','N','Y','Y','Y','N','N','Y','N','Y','Y')
data.frame(Income_Level,Loan_Given)
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: `nums <- table(df$Income_Level, df$Loan_Given);
nums/rowSums(nums)`

Comment: Or use `prop.table`

Comment: This works. Thanks, I should have labeled the data frame. Sorry about that

Comment: `prop.table(table(df), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` tools, this is a `group_by` and then a `summarise`:

```r
Income_Level <- c('High','Low','Low','High',
                  'Low','High','High','High','Low','Low','High','Low')
Loan_Given <- c('Y','N','N','Y','Y','Y','N','N','Y','N','Y','Y')

library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Income_Level,Loan_Given) %>%
  group_by(Income_Level) %>%
  mutate(
    loan_lgl = case_when(
      Loan_Given == "Y" ~ TRUE,
      Loan_Given == "N" ~ FALSE
    )
  ) %>%
  summarise(pct_loan = 100 * mean(loan_lgl)) %>%
  print()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Income_Level pct_loan
#>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 High             66.7
#> 2 Low              50.0
```